# Getting error while installing therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, therubyracer

I am receiving an error while bundle install my updates. Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'libv8'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem "bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails", "~> 0.3.1.10"
gem 'hpricot'
gem "rest-open-uri", "~> 1.0.0"
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem "commonjs", "~> 0.2.6"
  gem "less", "~> 2.2.2"
  gem "less-rails", "~> 2.2.6"
end


gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

Here is an error i am getting after running bundle install command on production:

> An error occured while installing therubyracer (0.11.0), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

Comment: did you try to install libv8 manually before running bundle install ? is it the only error message you get ?

Answer (score 9):

I did the following that worked for me:

- I commented out therubyracer from my Gemfile
- ran "bundle install"
- installed the newest version of therubyracer using "gem install therubyracer" (at the time of writing this is 0.11.2)
- I uncommented therubyracer to put it back in to my Gemfile
- ran "bundle install" again and everything works

Comment: I ran ```bundle update therubyracer``` and that worked out for me. I guess my v8 installation wasn't matching my proper ```therubyracer``` version.

Comment: 2018 and here I am... on AWS Cloud9

`gem install therubyracer` results in `Successfully installed therubyracer-0.12.3`

putting the gem back in my gemfile results in 

`Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "libv8":` + `In Gemfile: mini_racer was resolved to 0.1.3, which depends on libv8 (~> 5.0)` + `therubyracer (= 0.12.3) was resolved to 0.12.3, which depends on libv8 (~> 3.16.14.15)` + `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mini_racer": In Gemfile: mini_racer` + `Could not find gem 'mini_racer' in any of the sources.`

Answer (score 4):

Including `libv8` in the `Gemfile` seems to be a fix to that:

```
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8.3'
```

via https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/215

Answer (score 2):

```
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

If it still does not work, just try to intall NodeJS

Answer (score 2):

I did a gem uninstall therubyracer & gem uninstall libv8, then remove libv8 from the gemfile and just use therubyracer, then run 'bundle install'

Answer (score 1):

probably, your libv8 version and therubyracer version are not matching.

So, either you can include proper libv8 version in the Gemfile, which is similar to the 
jibiel's solution

```
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8.3'
```

But, I would prefer to do these two steps, So, that you don't have to worry about finding proper version of libv8:

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

`terminal`

```
gem uninstall libv8
bundle install
```

And, that is what I have done to solve my same problem